# How can I divide these two sparse matrices together?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to move dense matrix operations to be sparse. I was using numpy broadcasting to divide an array of shape (432,) to (591, 432) when they were dense, but how can do I this with sparse matrices?

```
<591x432 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3876 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>


<1x432 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 432 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

When I try with this dummy data below...

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

matrix = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(raw_documents=["test sentence.", "test sent 2.").T
max_w = np.max(matrix, axis=0)
matrix / max_w
```

I get `ValueError: inconsistent shapes`. How can I divide these ?

Comment: I'm unsure if there's a better way to do this, but `matrix / max_w.todense()` seems to work, and presumably max_w already has non-zero values everywhere, (or else why would you be dividing by it?) so there's no cost to converting to dense.

Comment: `scipy.sparse` doesn't not implement `broadcasting`.  These matrices are not a subclass of `ndarray`, though their attritubes may be arrays.  If the sparcity is the same, it may be possible to divide the `data` attributes elementwise.  But generally speaking, division by the implicit 0s in the divisor will give problems.  There is a `csr.multiply` but no `divide`.

Comment: I believe `sklearn` has some sparse utility functions, that may include a 'normalizion', e.g. `sklearn.utils.sparsefuncs.inplace_csr_column_scale`

Comment: Element-wise division and matrix division are two very different thing. It looks like you want the former and not the later. Still, a division by a sparse matrix does not make much sense since items are assumed to be mostly 0 (otherwise using a sparse matrix does not make any sense). Divisions by zeros are not mathematically defined... If you know that the values are not zeros (are you sure?), then you can convert it to a dense matrix and compute the element-wise inverse so to then multiply the final matrix by the computed inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to, you can divide by multiplying by the reciprocal.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix, coo_matrix
A = csc_matrix([[3, 4], [5, 6]])
B = A.max(axis=0)
res = A.multiply(B.power(-1.))
ref = A/B.todense()
np.allclose(res.todense(), ref)  # True
```

But in your case, there may not be a speed advantage compared to dividing by `B.todense()`.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix, coo_matrix
rng = np.random.default_rng(452349345693456)

# generate arrays like yours
shape = (591, 432)
nnz = 3876
A = rng.random(size=shape)
b = np.partition(A.ravel(), nnz)[nnz]
A[A >= b] = 0
A = csc_matrix(A)
assert A.nnz == nnz
B = A.max(axis=0)

# compare solutions
res = A.multiply(B.power(-1.))
ref = A/B.todense()
np.allclose(res.todense(), ref)  # True

%timeit A.multiply(B.power(-1.))
# 1.3 ms ± 734 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit A/B.todense()
# 306 µs ± 10.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Yeah I went down the reciprocal route after the comments from Jérôme Richard, but also found no speedup, I'll mark this as accepted anyhow as validates what I was seeing from my side.